# How to Dock a Palette to a Notebook (not using the DockedCells[] function)

Tags: palettes, docked-cell

Is it possible to dock a palette to a notebook?

First of all, I know how to work with the DockedCell[] function.  However, this function will not achieve what I am looking for.  Docked cells are great for presenting information docked horizontally at the top of a notebook.  However, I have information I want docked on vertically on the side of a notebook.

I'm thinking a good way to do this is to dock a palette.  I know how to create palettes and work with them.  However, I do not know how to dock them to a notebook and stay docked when I move the notebook.

I know how to grab the current window margins for the notebook. This can be done with:

```
Dynamic[AbsoluteCurrentValue[InputNotebook[], {WindowMargins}]]
```

Now, I just need to have the palette dynamically move when the values above change.  Is this possible?  I'm thinking it must be possible somehow since the DockedCell[] does this.

Comment: Or.... if you can think of any other techniques for content that runs vertically that is docked somehow I would be interested.

Comment: What should happen when the palette/ notebook is opened/closed?

Comment: I'd like the palette to open and dock to the notebook when I open the notebook.  I'd like the palette to close when I close the notebook.  I'm planning disable the open/close buttons on the palette itself.  I think could do this by using the frameless option for the palette.

Comment: One can set Dynamic WindowSize and WindowMargins for the parent notebook so that it will adjust options for given palette but I don't see it being smooth.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes... I was able to do this today with dynamic and current value setting the update interval to .01.  You are correct... it is definitely jumpy... ruins the experience.  : /  I guess I figured there would be something built into Mathematica that would run a lot smoother like docked cell do... but maybe not.

Comment: Events handling is not the best part of Mathematia. I will try to play with this problem somewhere around the weekend, we will see.

Comment: A docked cell is a cell within the same notebook and it is part of the same window.  A palette is a separate notebook and a separate window. I doubt that the level of integration you are asking for is possible.  I'm sure it's possible to hack something together but it will be troublesome, fragile and not very well behaved (e.g. the palette probably cannot move with the window continuously, but can "jump" to the site when you stop moving the window).

Comment: I see.  It sounds like I am limited to using docked cells if I want a smooth docking experience.  As far as I know, all cells span horizontally and its not possible to split notebooks into two columns each with its own set of cells.  That would be a great feature to add in a future update.